# How to get the latest MBEWH~LBKUM value?

Tags: abap, opensql

This program is actually used to calculate the total stock with a limit from the posting date (MATDOC-BUDAT). But I have a problem in determining the initial stock. The initial stock (MBEWH-LBKUM) is taken from the month before the month the posting date was made. But in the program that I made, the initial stock data (MBEWH-LBKUM) that appeared was not updated as it should. Meanwhile, if referring to the posting date (matdoc-budat / the query I joined to the matdoc table), the initial stock data that should appear, is just not like that.

But if I only select the posting date in a short period of time, the results that appear are correct

My Query is :

```
FORM F_GETDT .

  REFRESH: IT_ZVBR.

    SELECT DISTINCT MARA~MATNR
                    MATDOC~BUDAT
                    MATDOC~BWART
                    MATDOC~SHKZG
                    MATDOC~WERKS
                    MATDOC~MENGE AS TOTAL
    FROM MARA
    INNER JOIN MATDOC ON MARA~MATNR = MATDOC~MATNR
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE IT_ZVBR
    WHERE MATDOC~WERKS = P_WERKS AND
          MATDOC~BUDAT IN P_BUDAT AND
          MARA~MATKL IN ('E001', 'E002', 'E003', 'E005', 'E006', 'E007', 'E008', 'E009', 'E010', 'E011', 'E012', 'E014').
ENDFORM.
```

This is my code to fill the internal table IT_PRINT which is later displayed:

```
FORM F_LSTDT.

  CLEAR: WA_ZVBR, WA_PRINT, V_TEMP, V_DATE, V_MONTH, V_MONTHMIN, V_YEAR.

  SORT IT_ZVBR BY MATNR.
  IT_TEMP = IT_ZVBR.
  DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM IT_ZVBR COMPARING MATNR.

  LOOP AT IT_ZVBR INTO WA_ZVBR.

    WA_PRINT-PSTAR = P_BUDAT-LOW.
    WA_PRINT-PFINS = P_BUDAT-HIGH.
    WA_PRINT-MATNR = WA_ZVBR-MATNR.

    SELECT SINGLE MAKTX FROM MAKT
    INTO WA_PRINT-MAKTX
    WHERE MATNR = WA_PRINT-MATNR.

    LOOP AT IT_TEMP INTO WA_TEMP WHERE MATNR = WA_ZVBR-MATNR.

      CLEAR: V_TEMP.
      V_TEMP = WA_TEMP-BUDAT+6(2).
      V_DATE = V_TEMP.

      CLEAR: V_TEMP.
      V_TEMP = WA_TEMP-BUDAT+4(2).
      V_MONTH = V_TEMP.
      V_MONTHMIN = V_MONTH - 1.

      CLEAR: V_TEMP.
      V_TEMP = WA_TEMP-BUDAT+0(4).
      V_YEAR = V_TEMP.

      BLN_SBLM = 12.
      THN_SBLM = V_YEAR - 1.

      IF V_MONTH = 1.
        SELECT SINGLE LBKUM FROM MBEWH
          INTO WA_PRINT-LBKUM
          WHERE MATNR = WA_PRINT-MATNR AND
            LFMON = BLN_SBLM AND
            LFGJA = THN_SBLM AND
            BWKEY = WA_ZVBR-WERKS.
      ELSE.
        SELECT SINGLE LBKUM FROM MBEWH
          INTO WA_PRINT-LBKUM
          WHERE MATNR = WA_PRINT-MATNR AND
            LFMON = V_MONTHMIN AND
            LFGJA =  V_YEAR AND
            BWKEY = WA_ZVBR-WERKS.
      ENDIF.

     //Logic to swap to the latest value  
      IF WA_PRINT-LBKUM = WA_PRINT-TEMP.
          WA_PRINT-TEMP = WA_PRINT-LBKUM.
      ELSEIF WA_PRINT-LBKUM <> WA_PRINT-TEMP AND WA_PRINT-LBKUM > 0.
          CLEAR: WA_PRINT-TEMP.
          WA_PRINT-TEMP = WA_PRINT-LBKUM.
      ENDIF.

  WA_PRINT-LBKUM = WA_PRINT-TEMP.

    ENDLOOP.
    APPEND WA_PRINT TO IT_PRINT.
    SORT IT_PRINT BY MATNR.
    CLEAR: WA_ZVBR, WA_PRINT, WA_TEMP, V_TEMP, V_DATE, V_MONTH, V_MONTHMIN, V_YEAR.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDFORM.
```

It supposed to get data which is in the picture below (tcode se16n):

[image: The data that have to be the output]

Because in the matdoc table, there is latest transaction according posting date (BUDAT).

[image: Data based on posting date in matdoc]

And the data that i actually got is the previous data.

[image: The data is underlined with blue]

How to solve this problem? I've stuck in this problem for so long. Thanks before.

Comment: Please explain what you want to do with plain words, don't let people deduce that from the code. Let me do it for you, in short: I think your requirement is to read the stock MBEW from the month before the date in MATDOC. In your case, the issue is that the date is February 2020, but your program takes the stock from 2019. So, please edit your question. Moreover, you should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's not the case currently.

Comment: Yes, your deduction is correct sandra. Can you help me? Please...
Thanks before

Comment: I Change the logic to swap lbkum from this



`//Logic to swap to the latest value  
      IF WA_PRINT-LBKUM = WA_PRINT-TEMP.
          WA_PRINT-TEMP = WA_PRINT-LBKUM.
      ELSEIF WA_PRINT-LBKUM <> WA_PRINT-TEMP AND WA_PRINT-LBKUM > 0.
          CLEAR: WA_PRINT-TEMP.
          WA_PRINT-TEMP = WA_PRINT-LBKUM.
      ENDIF.`



Into this :


`MODIFY IT_PRINT FROM WA_PRINT TRANSPORTING LBKUM WHERE MATNR = WA_TEMP-MATNR.`




It still does not work as i hope

Comment: So many problems in your code that I can't even report them here (ask an experienced developer to help you). That said, if you debug, you can see that you read the corresponding stock for all dates of MATDOC, and you finally consider only the latest read. But the read order is random concerning the dates, so you finally get the stock of a random date. By the way, be careful, after each SELECT, test SY-SUBRC to proceed in case no line is found.

Answer (score 0):

In your horrific snippet you make a sorting which messes up the whole your idea:

```
SORT it_zvbr BY matnr.
it_temp = it_zvbr.
```

This makes BUDAT got sorted descending in each MATNR group and breaks your idea with LBKUM, the `SELECT LBKUM` after ELSE gets **overwritten** with each iteration of the loop, so it always keeps last value by itab sort order, so the earliest comes last.

To fix this, replace and put SORT after assigning `it_temp = it_zvbr`.

Taken all round, this whole piece is a mess and should be overwritten from scratch. Just speculating what you need here:

If you need total stock from MATDOC values to add it to initial stock from MBEWH previous to BUDAT month, then you need probably that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m~matnr,
                x~maktx,
                ew~lfgja AS initial_year,
                ew~lfmon AS initial_month,
                SUM( lp~menge ) AS total,
                MAX( ew~lbkum ) AS initial_stock
    FROM mara AS m
   INNER JOIN makt AS x
      ON m~matnr = x~matnr
   INNER JOIN matdoc AS mdoc
      ON lp~matnr = m~matnr
    LEFT OUTER JOIN mbewh AS ew
      ON ew~matnr = m~matnr
    INTO TABLE @DATA(it_stock)

   WHERE mdoc~WERKS = p_werks
     AND mdoc~budat IN p_budat 
     AND m~matkl IN ('E001', 'E002', 'E003', 'E005', 'E006', 'E007', 'E008', 'E009', 'E010', 'E011', 'E012', 'E014').
     AND ew~lfmon = ( SELECT MAX( lfmon ) 
                        FROM mbewh AS h 
                       WHERE h~matnr = m~matnr 
                         AND h~lfgja = mdoc~mjahr 
                         AND h~lfmon <> ( SELECT MAX( lfmon ) 
                                            FROM mbewh 
                                           WHERE matnr = h~matnr 
                                             AND lfgja = h~lfgja ) )
   GROUP BY mara~matnr, makt~maktx, ew~lfgja, ew~lfmon.
```

I am using `MJAHR` for subquery as it usually equal to `BUDAT` first 4 characters.

This solution uses nested subqueries by `MBEWH` to find previous to last value in each valuation period and this looks ugly as well, but it's anyway shorter than your raw piece.